# how to truncate button text in flex child

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble achieving a desired layout using flexbox.
I need one unshrinkable child, and two childs that can shrink/grow and be truncated according to their content while keeping into account their content sizes.

This works (using Tailwind CSS classes, but doesn't matter):

```
  <div class="flex items-stretch">
    <div class="flex-none">Lorem</div>
    <div class="flex-initial min-w-0">
      <div class="truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-initial min-w-0">
      <div class="truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ut mollis tortor, ut volutpat lacus.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this would yield the following:

[image]

And that's exactly what I want to achieve.
However, when replacing the child div with a button element, truncation doesn't kick in anymore and the parent gets overflowed.

```
  <div class="flex items-stretch">
    <div class="flex-none">Lorem</div>
    <div class="flex-initial min-w-0">
      <button class="truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-initial min-w-0">
      <button class="truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ut mollis tortor, ut volutpat lacus.</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

What am I missing to have button text truncated as well in this example?

Here's the code snippet:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/mHCJZeG0IX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give your button `max-width: 100%;`

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work. Any pointers on why a button needs max-width and a regular div doesn't?

Comment: glad that I could help. Button is an 'inline-block' element where as Properties of truncate works on 'block' elements only, such as div.